# Angular http.post multiple Array and add rows

Tags: angular, post, httprequest

Is there a easy way to post a multiple Array in Angular? For example my json (postData)

```
0:{company: "company1"}
1:{company: "company2"}
```

if I do http.post with data[0] all works fine with company1. But I want both entries inside in one way. Do I have to count array and make a for? Or is there a better way?
Thanks a lot

```
this.http.post(url,postData)
```

Comment: use a loop then insert as much data as you want

Comment: @Frost Can you give example?

Comment: lets say all you array is in `myNewArray: string[]` then write `for( let x of myNewArray ) { this.http.post(url,x) }`

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do something like

```
companies=[{"company1":"value"},{"company2":"value"}]
```

or

```
companies=["company1","company2"]
```

then you can use it in POST like

```
0:{company: companies}
```